# Como um inline style pode causar problemas de segurança?

Tags: api, segurança, twitter-api

Trabalhando com a API do Twitter, recebi a seguinte mensagem no navegador ao tentar efetuar a autenticação:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "style-src https://abs.twimg.com
>   https://abs-0.twimg.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-4Su6mBWzEIFnH4pAGMOuaeBrstwJN4Z3pq/s1Kn4/KQ='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Pesquisando sobre o problema, encontrei sobre o [Content Security Policy (CSP)](http://content-security-policy.com/) que dita algumas normas sobre segurança, mas não encontrei algo que explique como isso seria um problema.

Comment: Veja aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766817/refused-to-apply-inline-style-because-it-violates-the-following-content-security e esse outro link que fala como pode ser "inseguro" o inline http://dontkry.com/posts/code/disable-inline-styles.html